# Difficulty retrieving Parse Object Field Values

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am able to retrieve my "project" objects from Parse Core, and the "projectname" values which are then returned to me and printed to the log. I thought that these values would update my productNames array which is then to be displayed in my TableView. My prototype tableview cell is defined in the DealCell class with an image and a label. When I run the app, my tableView is empty. What did I miss?

My TableView's class:

```
var productIds = [String]()
var productNames = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.productIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.productNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    // Ask for the current user's personal list of saved PFObject IDs.
    let Ids = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("accepted") as! NSArray
    print(Ids)

    // Requesting the Project objects based on the Ids retrieved.
    let projectRetrieval = PFQuery(className: "project")
    projectRetrieval.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: Ids as [AnyObject])
    projectRetrieval.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {

                //Append the productNames array with retrieved projectnames
                self.productNames.append(object["projectname"] as! String)

                // This line successfully prints the array of product Names retrieved.
                print("Projectnames: \(self.productNames)")

            }
        }
    })

}

// Number of Rows
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.productNames.count;
}

// Assign the productNames to the labels in each cell.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dealcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DealCell

    cell.productName.text = self.productNames[indexPath.row] 

    return cell

}
```

My print output is strange, it looks like this, but it is getting the projectnames successfully:

```
Projectnames: ["Personal Drone"]
Projectnames: ["Personal Drone", "Prosthetic Limb Patent"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **refresh** your tableview with this method;

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

You can put this code after your findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock callback closure in your case;

```
projectRetrieval.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {

                //Append the productNames array with retrieved projectnames
                self.productNames.append(object["projectname"] as! String)

                // This line successfully prints the array of product Names retrieved.
                print("Projectnames: \(self.productNames)")

            }
        }
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Comment: Added that in, also realized that the functions weren't named properly. Ran it again after fixes, still no results in my tableView.

Comment: Add the self.tableView.reloadData() method with your findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock closure. I edited my answer just try the copy paste my codes.

Comment: You are a SAINT! Thank you.